# How to put custom admin setting field into a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, admin-menu

I set up an admin settings menu and I'd like to output the fields as a short code.

The way I learned to output the fields from a tutorial was with:

```
<?php $input_examples = get_option('sandbox_theme_input_examples'); ?>
<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $input_examples[ 'textarea_example' ] ); ?>
```

But putting that into the shortcode doesn't work:

```
function shortcode()
{

return '<?php $input_examples = get_option('sandbox_theme_input_examples'); ?>';
return '<?php echo sanitize_text_field( $input_examples[ 'textarea_example' ] ); ?>';

}
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode');
```

I'm guessing there is a specific way to put php code into the shortcodes that I'm not understanding?

I've looked all over and can't find a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues aren't shortcode-related, just some PHP syntax problems. I suggest [enabling debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) so you can see PHP errors being generated.

Opening `<?php` and closing `?>` php tags are for switching between html and php output. See [escaping from html in PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

A function can only `return` once, as it immediately ends execution and exits the function. See [`return` in PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).

It also couldn't hurt to familiarize yourself with [strings and the proper use of single and double quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

```
function shortcode()
{
    $input_examples = get_option('sandbox_theme_input_examples');
    return '<img src="' . sanitize_text_field( $input_examples[ 'textarea_example' ] ) . '">';
}
add_shortcode('shortcode', 'shortcode');
```

Comment: That worked! And I'm very new to PHP just trying to learn as I go so thank you for the extra materials I'll read up on them!

One more question though - How would I insert an html string into this though? For instance if the text field is a URL that I want converted into an HTML img string.

Comment: see edit above.